# Could not find kotlin-reflect.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.1.3-2) in android studio 3.0

Tags: android, kotlin

I have downloaded Android Studio 3.0 have built my project, I got this error, how to fix that?

`Could not find kotlin-reflect.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.1.3-2).`

Searched in the following locations: **file:/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.1.3-2/kotlin-reflect-1.1.3-2.jar**

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html

Comment: use `1.1.4-3` version .